# Wordpress hide actions from functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook, custom-wordpress-pages

I added some actions hooks in functions.php & i don't want customer to see those hooks. Please help me how ?

I tried, to create a new file then add the code and attach it in functions.php but after doing this code not work.. Please help me.        Please help me into this. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, in what way doesn't it work and what is the exact way you have attached them on? In my experience an import statement works fine.

Comment: i m adding code for email.. BCC code.

Comment: i uploaded file at this destination, also added this code in FUNCTIONS.php file.. but it doesnt work..

require ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/deprecated-hooks.php';

Comment: are you sure you've got the right directory (the live site may have a different structure than your local version)? Also you can use include to make it not cause a fatal error on import failure and only a warning so you can then use functions.php to do further debugging

Comment: i just need to add 1 action hook in functions.php without wrinting the code openly in functions.php.. Please let me know how can i do this ? Please

Comment: yes by including the PHP file using include or require. Mind you they'll still be able to go and see the file at its actual location. But you can't really hide anything in a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a simple one-php-file plugin for your code.

There is an example in /wp-content/plugins/hello.php. It's Matt Mullenweg's Hello Dolly plugin. Copy it and change it. Don't forget to activate it from the Plugins panel when you're ready to go live with it.

Writing plugins for public distribution is a big job, but writing one-off plugins for customers is much easier.